# Can I check if a wix property is contained in another property?

Tags: wix

I need to check if a certain wix property is contained in another property, in order to use this condition for running a custom action. Basically I'm checking if the `Path` environment variable has a certain path in it. This is what I have:

```
<Custom Action="MyCustomAction" After="InstallFinalize" >
  <![CDATA[NOT(PathEnvVarProperty><MyCustomPath)]]> <!-- check if MyCustomPath included in Path env var-->
</Custom>
```

Note that I do read the `Path` environment variable into `PathEnvVarProperty`.

It doesn't seem to be working; the logfile shows that `PathEnvVarProperty` does include `MyCustomPath`, but my custom action is still being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had in my question actually does work, I was just having a different issue which led me to think it wasn't working.